# Docker postgresql image with initdb.sql

Tags: docker, psql

I'm running postgres image on docker-compose setup.

With Dockerfile I copy

```
COPY --chown=pg:pg psql-tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/psql-tables.sql
```

And from docker log it seems that create-table script gets executed.

But no tables created !?!

Whats wrong with this ?

I can run the script inside container after it is up and running. DB tables created just fine.

psqldb logs:

```
/usr/localbin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initeb.d psal-tables.sql
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
```

Comment: can you share the output that indicates that the script was executed?

Comment: Added log rows.

Comment: it looks like there are some typos in `/docker-entrypoint-initeb.d psal-tables.sql` -- is that the actual output?

Comment: also, can you share the full `Dockerfile`? perhaps another command is overwriting the table

Comment: I am using 2 laptops, and can not copy between ... (This is my private one.) Just checked tho typos. In original seems OK.

Comment: In Dockerfile there is just "FROM postgres" and 2. row "COPY..."

Answer (score 0):

When working with external scripts, you can simply map the directory as a volume like so:

```
$ mkdir scripts
$ echo "create table foo (id int, name text);" >> scripts/create-table.sql
$ echo "insert into foo values (generate_series(1,10),'foo');" >> scripts/create-table.sql
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -v ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -d postgres
b519461622f26b1bddf0b38a4b840ecd2f712751d78bbc46808c2268f3cb7164

$ dx some-postgres psql postgres postgres -c "select * from foo"
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | foo
  2 | foo
  3 | foo
  4 | foo
  5 | foo
  6 | foo
  7 | foo
  8 | foo
  9 | foo
 10 | foo
(10 rows)
```

Comment: I am not able to use volumes in this setup used by automated test scripts.